# PuPHPet build error - invalid option: --manifestdir

Tags: php, vagrant, puppet, puphpet

I am giving [PuPHPet](https://puphpet.com/) a go, so created an archive using all the basic options.
When trying `vagrant up` I get the error:

> ==> machine1: Error: Could not parse application options: invalid option: --manifestdir

A little bit of investigation points to the problem being with puppet V5 not longer supports `manifest_dir` option.
The suggested fix is to update the config to use environments and set `environment` and `environments_path` in config.

Can anyone throw some light on where in the `config.yaml` these need to be set?
Also where in the PuPHPet directory structure the environment folder needs to live?

The config.yaml that I am using;

```
vagrantfile:
    target: local
    vm:
        provider:
            local:
                box: bento/ubuntu-16.04
                box_url: 'false'
                box_version: '0'
                chosen_virtualizer: virtualbox
                virtualizers:
                    virtualbox:
                        modifyvm:
                            natdnshostresolver1: false
                        showgui: 0
                    vmware:
                        numvcpus: 1
                    parallels:
                        linked_clone: 0
                        check_guest_tools: 0
                        update_guest_tools: 0
                machines:
                    vflm_k8bgkk2q1t9z:
                        id: machine1
                        hostname: machine1.puphpet
                        network:
                            private_network: 192.168.56.101
                            forwarded_port:
                                vflmnfp_yru3n3tlfqio:
                                    host: '9419'
                                    guest: '22'
                        memory: '512'
                        cpus: '1'
        provision:
            puppet:
                manifests_path: puphpet/puppet/manifests
                module_path:
                    - puphpet/puppet/modules
                    - puphpet/puppet/manifests
                options:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
        synced_folder:
            vflsf_lvspa9n8sfn3:
                owner: www-data
                group: www-data
                source: ./
                target: /var/www
                sync_type: default
                smb:
                    smb_host: ''
                    smb_username: ''
                    smb_password: ''
                    mount_options:
                        dir_mode: '0775'
                        file_mode: '0664'
                rsync:
                    args:
                        - '--verbose'
                        - '--archive'
                        - '-z'
                    exclude:
                        - .vagrant/
                        - .git/
                    auto: 'true'
        usable_port_range:
            start: 10200
            stop: 10500
        post_up_message: ''
    ssh:
        host: 'false'
        port: 'false'
        private_key_path: 'false'
        username: vagrant
        guest_port: 'false'
        keep_alive: '1'
        forward_agent: 'false'
        forward_x11: 'false'
        shell: 'bash -l'
        insert_key: 'false'
    vagrant:
        host: detect
    proxy:
        http: ''
        https: ''
        ftp: ''
        no_proxy: ''
server:
    install: '1'
    packages:
        - bash-completion
        - htop
        - vim
users_groups:
    install: '1'
    groups: {  }
    users: {  }
locale:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        default_locale: en_US.UTF-8
        locales:
            - en_GB.UTF-8
            - en_US.UTF-8
        timezone: UTC
firewall:
    install: '1'
    rules: {  }
resolv:
    install: '1'
    nameservers:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
    domainname: ''
    searchpath: {  }
cron:
    install: '1'
    jobs: {  }
nginx:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: present
        default_vhost: 1
        proxy_buffers: '4 256k'
        proxy_buffer_size: 128k
        proxy_connect_timeout: 600s
        proxy_send_timeout: 600s
        proxy_read_timeout: 600s
        names_hash_bucket_size: 128
    upstreams: {  }
    vhosts:
        nxv_9iotkb0epf2c:
            server_name: awesome.dev
            server_aliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            www_root: /var/www/awesome
            listen_port: '80'
            client_max_body_size: 1m
            ssl: '0'
            locations:
                nxvl_jjk47mtl0r5o:
                    www_root: /var/www/awesome/web
                    location: /
                    autoindex: 'off'
                    internal: 'false'
                    index_files:
                        - index.html
                        - index.php
                        - app.php
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                        - /index.php$is_args$args
                        - /app.php$is_args$args
                    fastcgi: ''
                    fastcgi_index: ''
                    fastcgi_split_path: ''
                    proxy: ''
                    proxy_redirect: ''
                nxvl_8j0icnvn334t:
                    www_root: /var/www/awesome/web
                    location: '~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$)'
                    autoindex: 'off'
                    internal: 'false'
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                        - /app_dev.php$is_args$args
                    fastcgi: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                    fastcgi_index: app_dev.php
                    fastcgi_split_path: '^(.+\.php)(/.*)$'
                    fast_cgi_params_extra:
                        - 'SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name'
                        - 'APP_ENV dev'
                    set:
                        - '$path_info $fastcgi_path_info'
                    proxy: ''
                    proxy_redirect: ''
                nxvl_fan1klxugnqt:
                    www_root: /var/www/awesome/web
                    location: '~ ^/index\.php(/|$)'
                    autoindex: 'off'
                    internal: 'false'
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                        - /index.php$is_args$args
                    fastcgi: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                    fastcgi_index: index.php
                    fastcgi_split_path: '^(.+\.php)(/.*)$'
                    fast_cgi_params_extra:
                        - 'SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name'
                    set:
                        - '$path_info $fastcgi_path_info'
                    proxy: ''
                    proxy_redirect: ''
                nxvl_5grri35wy80b:
                    www_root: /var/www/awesome/web
                    location: '~ ^/app\.php(/|$)'
                    autoindex: 'off'
                    internal: 'false'
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                        - /app.php$is_args$args
                    fastcgi: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                    fastcgi_index: app.php
                    fastcgi_split_path: '^(.+\.php)(/.*)$'
                    fast_cgi_params_extra:
                        - 'SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name'
                        - 'APP_ENV prod'
                    set:
                        - '$path_info $fastcgi_path_info'
                    proxy: ''
                    proxy_redirect: ''
    proxies: {  }
apache:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: 2.4
        user: www-data
        group: www-data
        default_vhost: true
        manage_user: false
        manage_group: false
        sendfile: 0
    modules:
        - proxy_fcgi
        - rewrite
    vhosts:
        av_2bg7c7vda1pb:
            servername: awesome.dev
            serveraliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            docroot: /var/www/awesome/web
            port: '80'
            setenvif:
                - 'Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1'
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl: '0'
            ssl_cert: LETSENCRYPT
            ssl_key: LETSENCRYPT
            ssl_chain: LETSENCRYPT
            ssl_certs_dir: LETSENCRYPT
            ssl_protocol: ''
            ssl_cipher: ''
            directories:
                avd_ayxmp8ol7nqw:
                    path: /var/www/awesome/web
                    directoryindex: 'index.php app.dev'
                    options:
                        - Indexes
                        - FollowSymlinks
                        - MultiViews
                    allow_override:
                        - All
                    require:
                        - 'all granted'
                    custom_fragment: ''
                    provider: directory
            files_match:
                avfm_5mduocupch06:
                    path: (app_dev|config)\.php$
                    sethandler: 'proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000'
                    setenv:
                        - 'APP_ENV dev'
                    custom_fragment: ''
                    provider: filesmatch
                avfm_h7xbhb0zqsoq:
                    path: app\.php$
                    sethandler: 'proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000'
                    setenv:
                        - 'APP_ENV prod'
                    custom_fragment: ''
                    provider: filesmatch
                avfm_bgd9dcbawlo8:
                    path: \.php$
                    sethandler: 'proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000'
                    custom_fragment: ''
                    provider: filesmatch
letsencrypt:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        email: ''
        webserver_service: ''
    domains: {  }
php:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '7.2'
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - xml
        pear: {  }
        pecl: {  }
    ini:
        display_errors: 'On'
        error_reporting: '-1'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
        date.timezone: UTC
    fpm_ini:
        error_log: /var/log/php-fpm.log
    fpm_pools:
        phpfp_kk90qv3if70v:
            ini:
                prefix: www
                listen: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                security.limit_extensions: .php
                user: www-user
                group: www-data
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
xdebug:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        xdebug.default_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_autostart: '0'
        xdebug.remote_connect_back: '1'
        xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
        xdebug.remote_port: '9000'
blackfire:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        server_id: ''
        server_token: ''
        agent:
            http_proxy: ''
            https_proxy: ''
            log_file: stderr
            log_level: '1'
        php:
            agent_timeout: '0.25'
            log_file: ''
            log_level: '1'
xhprof:
    install: '0'
wpcli:
    install: '0'
    version: v1.1.0
drush:
    install: '0'
    version: 8.0.5
ruby:
    install: '1'
    versions:
        rv_45pl5r1olefv:
            default: '1'
            bundler: '1'
            version: '2.4'
            gems:
                - deep_merge@1.2.1
                - activesupport@5.1.4
                - vine@0.4
python:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
    versions: {  }
nodejs:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: '6'
    npm_packages: {  }
mariadb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: '10.1'
        root_password: '123'
        override_options: {  }
    users:
        mariadbnu_lxzy8vptfdcv:
            name: dbuser
            password: '123'
    databases:
        mariadbnd_vch18hn8fy7h:
            name: dbname
            sql: ''
    grants:
        mariadbng_dkhxul0k78c2:
            user: dbuser
            table: '*.*'
            privileges:
                - ALL
mysql:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '5.7'
        root_password: '123'
        override_options: {  }
    users:
        mysqlnu_rew8wtlnfqjm:
            name: dbuser
            password: '123'
    databases:
        mysqlnd_xmr4nhv1e4ki:
            name: dbname
            sql: ''
    grants:
        mysqlng_eg463msh1guu:
            user: dbuser
            table: '*.*'
            privileges:
                - ALL
postgresql:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        global:
            encoding: UTF8
            version: '9.6'
        server:
            postgres_password: '123'
    databases: {  }
    users: {  }
    grants: {  }
mongodb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        bind_ip: 127.0.0.1
        port: '27017'
    globals:
        version: 3.6.2
    databases: {  }
redis:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        port: '6379'
sqlite:
    install: '0'
    databases: {  }
mailhog:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        smtp_ip: 0.0.0.0
        smtp_port: 1025
        http_ip: 0.0.0.0
        http_port: '8025'
        path: /usr/local/bin/mailhog
beanstalkd:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        listenaddress: 0.0.0.0
        listenport: '11300'
        maxjobsize: '65535'
        maxconnections: '1024'
        binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
        binlogfsync: null
        binlogsize: '10485760'
    beanstalk_console: 0
rabbitmq:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        port: '5672'
    users: {  }
    vhosts: {  }
    plugins: {  }
elastic_search:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 6.1.2
        java_install: true
    instances:
        esi_qgdjc41v6s8n:
            name: es-01
            jvm_options:
                - '-Xms2G'
                - '-Xmx2G'
```

Comment: Sounds like you are using an old version of Vagrant from before this fix was implemented.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I am using vagrant 1.9.1, which is above PuPHPet's min of 1.8.6. What version is vagrant is required?

Comment: I thought this was fixed in Vagrant a while ago, but it turns out: https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/pull/8797. So you need to upgrade to 1.9.8. Also, sounds like PuPHPet needs a PR for this.

Comment: @MattSchuchard out of curiosity, do you know how to setup the PuPHPet archive to use environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:**

Open `puphpet/vagrant/Vagrantfile-local`

**Step 2:**

Find this line of code:

```
puppet.manifests_path = "#{data['vm']['provision']['puppet']['manifests_path']}"
```

**Step 3:**

Insert these two lines of code before the line of code previously mentioned in `step 2`

```
puppet.environment_path = "#{data['vm']['provision']['puppet']['environment_path']}"
puppet.environment      = "#{data['vm']['provision']['puppet']['environment']}"
```

It should look like this now:

[image: Vagrantfile-local]

---

**Step 4:**

open `puphpet/config.yaml`

**Step 5:**

Find this line of code:

```
manifests_path: puphpet/puppet/manifests
```

**Step 6:**

Insert these two lines of code before the line of code previously mentioned in `step 5`

```
environment_path: puphpet/puppet/environments
environment: development
```

It should look like this now:

[image]

**Step 7:**

Go to `puphpet/puppet` directory and create a new directory and name it `environments` and inside the `environments` directory, create another directory and name it `development`

The structure should look like the one below:
[image]

**And you're done!!!**

But make sure to run `vagrant provision` to load the new configuration.